# Compiling Perl on ARM: Undefined reference to '__stack_chk_guard'

Tags: perl, arm

Right, so I'm compiling perl on an ARM device. It configures fine, so I start the compiling process. After the dependencies are done, I get this output:

```
cc -L/lib -L/usr/lib -L/usr/local/lib -o miniperl \
              gv.o toke.o perly.o pad.o regcomp.o dump.o util.o mg.o reentr.o mro.o keywords.o hv.o av.o run.o pp_hot.o sv.o pp.o scope.o pp_ctl.o pp_sys.o doop.o doio.o regexec.o utf8.o taint.o deb.o universal.o globals.o perlio.o perlapi.o numeric.o mathoms.o locale.o pp_pack.o pp_sort.o   \
            miniperlmain.o opmini.o perlmini.o -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lc 
gv.o: In function `Perl_gv_stashpvn':
gv.c:(.text+0x5794): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_fail'
gv.c:(.text+0x5798): undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
```

the same for a load of other files as well. I have tried:

- -fno-stack-protector, -fstack-protector, -fstack-protector-all: No effect
- -lssp: Can't find the file. There is no file called 'libssp' on my system
- Looking for the source code for libssp so I can compile it myself and link to it manually, can't find it

Any ideas?

Comment: You may want to provide more information, perl verion, OS & version, flags to ./Configure.

Comment: Ok... perl 5.14.0, linux 2.6.12.6-arm1, no ./Configure flags

Comment: you might have some luck running ./Configure -Accflags="-fno-stack-protector" then rebuilding. if not, I'd consider sending a bug report to p5p. (adding -fno-stack-protector to just the line above won't work as it's only linking).

Comment: You may want to check the GCC runtime version.  See discussion at http://discuss.joyent.com/viewtopic.php?id=26834.

Answer (score 5):

Posting an answer to get this question off the "unanswered" list...

Per @Alex's comment on the original question, the solution was to run

```
./Configure -Accflags="-fno-stack-protector"
```

and then rebuild. The important point is that you must *compile* every source file with `-fno-stack-protector` in order to get rid of the calls to `__stack_chk_guard`. Manually passing `-fno-stack-protector` during the *linking* stage doesn't do anything useful.